# Plotting a chessboard with no external libraries

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, chess

I'd like if someone could help me with this problem I've been hours trying to solve. 
 I have to plot a chessboard with no external libraries (using only the default graphical functions in R).

My attempt is working with black squares till I have to filter and paint the white squares:

```
plot(c(1:9),c(1:9),type="n")
for (i in 1:8){
rect(i,1:9,i+1,9,col="black",border="white")
}
```

I could do it manually in this way, but I know there's a simpler way:

```
plot(c(1:9),c(1:9),type="n")
rect(1, 2, 2, 1,col="black",border="white")
rect(4, 1, 3, 2,col="black",border="white")
rect(6, 1, 5, 2,col="black",border="white")
rect(7, 1, 8, 2,col="black",border="white")
(...)
```

I've tried adding a function to filter even numbers inside the loop but doesn't seems to works for me. 
I would appreciate any suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

Use `image` and just repeat 0:1 over and over.  Then you can mess with the limits a bit to make it fit nice.

```
image(matrix(1:0, 9, 9), col=0:1, xlim=c(-.05,.93), ylim=c(-.05,.93))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `col=` argument in your solution as shown.  Also note that `c(1:9)` can be written as just `1:9` :

```
plot(1:9, 1:9, type = "n")
for (i in 1:8) {
  col <- if (i %% 2) c("white", "black") else c("black", "white")
  rect(i, 1:9, i+1, 9, col = col, border = "white")
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

remembering Jeremy Kun's post
https://jeremykun.com/2018/03/25/a-parlor-trick-for-set/ on Set helped
me figure the hard part (for me) of this question.  i realized that
diagonals on the board (what bishops move on) have a constant color.
and, so, their Y-intercept (where they hit the Y-axis) will uniquely
determine their color, and adjacent Y values will have different
colors.  for a square at (x,y), the y intercept (since the slope is 1)
will be at Y == (y-x).  since the parity is the same for addition as
for subtraction, and i'm never sure which mod functions (in which
languages) may give a negative result, i use "(x+y) %% 2".

```
b <- matrix(nrow=8,ncol=8)              # basic board

colorindex <- (col(b)+row(b))%%2        # parity of the Y-intercept
                                        # for each square
colors <- c("red", "white")[colorindex+1] # choose colors
side <- 1/8                               # side of one square
ux <- col(b)*side                         # upper x values
lx <- ux-side                             # lower x values
uy <- row(b)*side                         # upper y
ly <- uy-side                             # upper y
plot.new()                                # initialize R graphics
rect(lx, ly, ux, uy, col=colors, asp=1)   # draw the board
```